# How to install Wi-Fi USB Dongle driver on raspberry pi 3?

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, raspberrypi, dongle

I am working on a raspberry pi 3. For a project the raspberry has to be in a 5 GHz Wi-Fi. Therefore we want to use a 5 GHz USB Wi-Fi Adapter (Edimax AC600 EW-7811ULC). The problem is that we can not install drivers for this USB Adapter.
When I try to execute "make" inside the driver folder (as recommended):

```
pi@XXXXXXXX:~/rtl88x2bu $ make
```

I get the following error:

```
make ARCH=armv7l CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.19.66-v7+/build M=/home/pi/rtl88x2bu  modules
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.66-v7+“ wird betreten
Makefile:614: arch/armv7l/Makefile: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
make[1]: *** Keine Regel, um „arch/armv7l/Makefile“ zu erstellen.  Schluss.
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.66-v7+“ wird verlassen
Makefile:2392: die Regel für Ziel „modules“ scheiterte
make: *** [modules] Fehler 2
```

"sudo" does not change anything.

Can anyone provide some help how to resolve this issue?

Thanks